# Linux cp command to preserve file strucutre

Tags: linux, shell, sh

So I have a linux file structure like this:

```
/base/dir_a/a/this_d=1_another/testfile
/base/dir_a/a/this_d=2_another/testfile
/base/dir_a/a/aa/this_d=1_another/testfile
/base/dir_a/a/ab/this_d=1_another/testfile
/base/dir_a/a/ab/this_d=2_another/testfile
```

I would like to copy over all folders containg `d=1` into `dir_b`

```
/base/dir_a/*d=1* -> /base/dir_b
```

So the final `dir_b` should be:

```
/base/dir_a/a/this_d=1_another/testfile
/base/dir_a/a/aa/this_d=1_another/testfile
/base/dir_a/a/ab/this_d=1_another/testfile
```

I tried a copy like the following (2 commands..)

```
cp /base/dir_a/a/*/*d=1* -> /base/dir_b;
cp /base/dir_a/a/*d=1* -> /base/dir_b;
```

But this will attempt to just copy the `this_d=1_another` folder into `/base/dir_b` which will cause issues because all of my nested folders are named the same.

How can I approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to use rsync if that's available to you:

```
rsync -avP --include=*/ --include=**/*d=1* --exclude='*' /base/dir_a /base/dir_b
```

However, this will create a bunch of empty directories as a side-effect.

Comment: No access to rsync.  I am using `hadoop distcp` which esentially mimics `cp` which is why I asked about `cp` since it will reach a much larger audiance then `hadoop distcp`